# WordPress MySQL Error Log

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am receiving this WordPress MySQL Error and I am not sure what the cause/solution is, IS this something to worry about?

```
[Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO wp_7_options (option_name, option_value, autoload) VALUES ('_transient_dash_4077549d03da2e451c8b5f002294ff51', 'http://wordpress.org/news/2013/10/wordpress-3-7-1/\' title=\'WordPress 3.7.1 is now available! This maintenance release addresses 11 bugs in WordPress 3.7, including: Images with captions no longer appear broken in the visual editor. Allow some sites running on old or poorly configured servers to continue to check for updates from WordPress.org. Avoid fatal errors with certain plugins that were incorrectly calling som […]\'>WordPress 3.7.1 Maintenance Release October 29, 2013WordPress 3.7.1 is now available! This maintenance release addresses 11 bugs in Wo
[Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO wp_7_options (option_name, option_value, autoload) VALUES ('_transient_dash_4077549d03da2e451c8b5f002294ff51', 'http://wordpress.org/news/2013/10/wordpress-3-7-1/\' title=\'WordPress 3.7.1 is now available! This maintenance release addresses 11 bugs in WordPress 3.7, including: Images with captions no longer appear broken in the visual editor. Allow some sites running on old or poorly configured servers to continue to check for updates from WordPress.org. Avoid fatal errors with certain plugins that were incorrectly calling som […]\'>WordPress 3.7.1 Maintenance Release October 29, 2013WordPress 3.7.1 is now available! This maintenance release addresses 11 bugs in Wo
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely something that should not both you unless you are using your binary log for point in time restore, database replication or something similar where you need to use the binary log. Basically the issue is that you are using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause on a table with multiple unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair the table "wp_7_options".